# AVX: "to 1 if not zero"

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics, avx

How can I turn the values of array of float32 numbers to 1 if they are not zero, using AVX?

For example:  `-0.2134f,  -1.23f,  -0.0f,  12.0f  ...`

becomes  `1.0f,   1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f  ...`

I assume, we should combine [_mm256_or_ps](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4172,4066&techs=AVX&text=or_) with some other instruction, but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first idea I would come up with is comparing the values to 0 and then ANDing that with a register full of 1s:

```
y = _mm256_and_ps(_mm256_cmp_ps(_mm256_setzero_ps(), x, _CMP_NEQ_OQ), _mm256_set1_ps(1.f));
```

This will AND all the 1s in the places where x is 0 with a bunch of 0s and fortunately an IEEE 754 zero is also an integer zero. The other values will get a floating point 1 ANDed with a bunch of 1s and thus an identity operation.

Answer (score 2):

Probably [vcmpps with a NE predicate](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpps), then _mm256_and_ps with the bit-pattern for `1.0f` is your best bet.

A false compare predicate gives you an all-zero bit-pattern which also conveniently represents `0.0f`.

all-ones & 1.0f = 1.0f.

Total of 2 single-uop instructions.  Using the compare result for a variable-blend would only be better if you wanted something other than 0.0f for the false case.

Comment: Minor correction: `_mm256_cmpne_ps` doesn't exist. For AVX there's only the general `_mm256_cmp_ps` intrinsic that takes the comparison function as an immediate value argument. I wasn't really aware of that either.

Comment: @ChrissaysReinstateMonica: oh yes, thanks.  Assemblers still implement mnemonics like `VCMPNEQ_OQPS`, but yeah Intel decided to just make a generic intrinsic for the new AVX predicates.  I always have to look that up when I need a `vcmpps` intrinsic.